# How to access an array in struct Codable, Identifiable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to access a nested array in my SwiftUI code.

I have an array that looks like this:

```
{
  "Count": 123,
  "someKey": [
    {
      "Id": 12345,
      "Images": [
        28008,
        28009
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the Images. So I came up with this code:

```
@ObservedObject var fetcherP = FetcherP()


public class FetcherP: ObservableObject {

    @Published var sightingsP = [someKeyP]()



    init(){
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {

    
     URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self](data,response,error) in
                do {
    
                    if let d = data {
                        
                        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootP.self, from: d)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.sightingsP = res.sightingsP
             
                        }
                             
                    }else {
                        print("No Data")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print (error)
                }
                
   
            }.resume()

}
        

}
```

and my codable:

```
struct RootP: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let someKeyP: [someKeyP]
    

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case count = "count"
        case someKeyP = "someKey"
    }
}


struct someKeyP: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id: Int
    public var images: [Int]

    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case id = "id"
           case images = "images"
         

        }
}
```

And this is how I try to use my code:

```
     ForEach(fetcherP.sightingsP) {myimages in
                
     **//How can I access the images here? I can't do foreach(myimages.images) {img in{

   Text(img)

}**

            }
```

Do I have to use double foreach? or is there any other way to do this?

any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the type `SightingsP` defined? Is it the same as `someKeyP`? Yes, if you need to access an array within an array, you would end up with nested `ForEach`s

Comment: @jnpdx, yes its same as someKey. When I try to use a nested foreach, I get this error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, what do you mean by fix?

Comment: @roozfar include a [mre]. When people have to guess about your code, it makes it much less likely you'll get a solution.

Comment: @jnpdx, thats exactly what I've done. the code in my question is a mini version of my code! I don't know how else I could make it any more "minimal"!

Comment: The types aren't even the same -- that's why I had to ask a question. And, `ForEach` is just floating in the middle of nothing. It's easy to make a copy-and-pastable example in SwiftUI, including everything someone would need to try your code. It's not just about "minimal" -- it's about "reproducible" as well. By the way, I haven't downvoted, but it wouldn't surprise me if the downvotes reflected this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, they are not generating error my end! not sure what you are doing to generate an error! I'm running the exact code now and no errors.

Comment: @jnpdx, ive edited my question/code. Also, the foreach is right after the NavigationView{ ... } in my view.

Comment: @roozfar Okay, but no one knows if you've even properly defined `fetcherP` on your view as a property because you've left the reader to guess about your code. See my answer for a complete, reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going wrong:

1. Your `CodingKeys` don't reflect the JSON -- case sensitivity matters
2. In `ForEach`, unless your model conforms to `Hashable`, you need to provide an `id` for it to use.
3. You can't provide an `Int` to `Text` -- you have to provide a `String` (I used string interpolation using `"\(intValue)"`)

```
let jsonData = """
    {
      "Count": 123,
      "someKey": [
        {
          "Id": 12345,
          "Images": [
            28008,
            28009
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

public class FetcherP: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var sightingsP = [someKeyP]()
    
    init(){
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        do {
            sightingsP = (try JSONDecoder().decode(RootP.self, from: jsonData)).someKeyP
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct RootP: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let someKeyP: [someKeyP]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case count = "Count"
        case someKeyP = "someKey"
    }
}

struct someKeyP: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id: Int
    public var images: [Int]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case images = "Images"
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var fetcherP = FetcherP()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(fetcherP.sightingsP, id: \.id) { myImages in
                ForEach(myImages.images, id: \.self) { imageNumber in
                    Text("\(imageNumber)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that what I've included here is a complete, reproducible example -- it can be copied and pasted into Xcode and tested.

Comment: Did this answer your question?